# SSRS 2005 Get Next Record Value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, reportingservices-2005

How do I get the next record in SSRS 2005?

SSRS 2005 has the Previous function but it doesn't have the Next function

Is there any other way to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 2):

A few ideas:

1. Shift your logic so that the first row of data is discarded, then on the next record, use Previous for the current row and the current row for "Next".
2. Add the desired data to your dataset so it is contained in additional columns. Perhaps some joins on `Row_Number()` to `Row_Number() + 1` could be in order.
3. Create a stored procedure that uses a temp table, and in it update additional columns with the next-row values. Be sure to turn off pre-validation so the SP won't blow up because of the temp tables (as when a stored procedure is run using `SET FMTONLY ON`, the temp tables will not get populated and validation will fail).

If you give more detail on what you're trying to accomplish, I might be able to come up with more ideas.